# files do not download in correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

Okay,

Basically i have been able to upload files to a SQL server database using asp.net and c#. I can view them no problem in the browser but when i download them they seem to lose their original format e.g. word documents lose their docx extension and you have to select to open them as word documents manually.

Here is my code so far

```
    //Method used to upload a file to the database
    protected void UploadBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stream inpStream = DocumentsUploadControl.PostedFile.InputStream;
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(inpStream);
        Byte[] size = br.ReadBytes ((int)inpStream.Length);

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=conn\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=new catalog;Integrated Security=True"))
        {

            string sql = "INSERT INTO Attachments(AttachmentReferenceID, AttachmentType, Filename, AttachmentDescription, FileUploadedBy, UploadDate)" + 
                "values (@Reference, @Type, @Filename, @Descr, @UploadedBy, @UploadedDate)";

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reference", ReferenceDDL.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", DocumentsUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentType.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Filename", FilenameTB.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Descr", size);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UploadedBy", Session["username"].ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UploadedDate", DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString());

                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();

                Response.Redirect("Documents.aspx");
            }

        }

    }


    //listener used to download the file
    protected void lnkDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton lnkbtn = sender as LinkButton;
        GridViewRow gvrow = lnkbtn.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
        int fileId = Convert.ToInt32(DocumentsGridView.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value.ToString());

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=conn\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=new catalog;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            string sql = "SELECT AttachmentReferenceID, AttachmentType, Filename, AttachmentDescription, FileUploadedBy, UploadDate FROM Attachments WHERE AttachmentID=@ID";

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", fileId);
                conn.Open();

                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    Response.ContentType = dr["AttachmentType"].ToString();
                    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + dr["Filename"] + "\"");
                    Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dr["AttachmentDescription"]);
                    Response.End();

                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: When it's saved, are you using your `FileName` field to get an extension for the file?

Comment: No i am using @Type to get the extension like this: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", DocumentsUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentType.ToString());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the extension/attachment type to the Response.AddHeader code like:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + dr["Filename"] + "." + dr["AttachmentType"].ToString());
```

Please try this one.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try appending application/ to your attachmenttype. I.e.

```
Response.contenttype = "application/" + dr["attachmenttype"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like (though I can't tell for sure) the value saved for filename relies on what the use types into a Textbox (FilenameTB), rather than the name of the file on disk?

If you were to look at PostedFile.FileName I think you could extract the extension?